# Checking docker container's stats from inside the container

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am writing a healthcheck routine for a docker container. By design it should check how much CPU and memory it's using and return an "unhealthy" `1` if they exceed limits.

Is there a way to check container CPU and memory usage from INSIDE the container by running a .sh script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All metrics are available in cgroup filesystem inside container. Read more here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics

Answer (score 0):

The client is connected to the docker socket (/var/run/docker.sock), which is not available inside the container. A workaround would be to **mount** host's /var/run/docker.sock into the container with the following option when you are starting the container:
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

For example, 
    docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock $MY_IMAGE_NAME

Comment: The container process gets **unlimited root-level access over the host** if you do this.  You usually don't want this, especially for simple health-checking.